# C++ I need to write a function that converts hexidecimal to decimal and uses recursion and I keep getting runtime errors

Tags: c++, recursion

This is for a class so it has to use recursion, I've written a working code iteratively, but I can't get it to work in recursion and I'm really lost. I've been working on this for a week. Any guidance or suggestions at all would be extremely helpful.

This is my function, I need to take in the hexadecimal as a char pointer and output it's corresponding decimal. I'm constantly getting either **stack overflow** or **memory allocation** runtime errors, can anyone identify what's wrong and steer me in the right direction?

```
 int hexToDecimal(const char *hex, int offset, int power){
  if(offset >= 0){
    hexChar = *(hex+offset);

    if( isalpha(hexChar) ) {
      hexChar = toupper(hexChar);
      hexNum = hexChar - asciiCharOffset;
    } else { 
      hexNum = hexChar - asciiIntOffset;
    }   
    return hexToDecimal(hex, offset--, power++) +  hexNum * (int)pow(16,power); 

  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you call this function? And where do you define `hexChar` and `hexNum`?

Comment: Where is the minimal working example reproducing the problem? What kind of errors are you getting? You cannot ask a question like this and expect a good answer, no psychics here.

Comment: I call in it main using this loop:  


       `while (input >> hex)`

        
 `{`

  `int offset = strlen(hex);`

  `int power  = 0;`

  `cout << hexToDecimal (hex, offset, power);`

 `}`

Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: I suggest taking a piece of paper, and a sample input string: 'A52B3', and pretending you're the computer. I think you'll quite quickly realise where you're going wrong with this function.

Comment: +1 for taking a week to figure this out before coming here.  I've seen enough who came here first before trying to figure anything out.

Comment: Looks like you're actually trying to convert hex to integer, not hex to decimal.  If you really want hex to decimal, you should first do hex to integer (what you're doing), then integer to decimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not compiled it, but first glance tells me that the corresponding line should be:

```
return hexToDecimal(hex, offset-1, power+1) +  hexNum * (int) pow(16,power-1);
```

Because in your case, you are calling yourself ad infinitum (being called with, lets say offset 6, if you pass offset-- it will still pass 6 because it will decrement after it gives the value to the function).

Also, the post-increment will give you undefined behavior for the call `pow(16,power)` later in the same expression, because (taking the example of power=6 again), it may be `pow(16,6)` or `pow(16,7)` depending on the compiler.

All that aside, there's also risk, that pow() will give you false (rounded down) value when converting to int (it may turnn out that pow(16,2) returns 255.9999999 and you end up with (int)255, there's ample evidence and solutions here on stackoverflow, just search for pow).

EDIT (in reply to comments):

Finally, introducing the magical printf debugger:

```
int hexToDecimal(const char *hex, int offset, int power){
  if(offset >= 0){
    char hexChar = *(hex+offset);
    int hexNum, 
        recursed;

    if( isalpha(hexChar) ) {
      hexChar = toupper(hexChar);
      hexNum = hexChar - asciiCharOffset;
    } 
    else { 
      hexNum = hexChar - asciiIntOffset;
    }   
    recursed= hexToDecimal(hexNum, offset-1, power+1); 

    printf("%d + %d * %d\n", recursed, hexNum, (int)pow(16,power-1));

    return recursed +  hexNum * (int)pow(16,power-1); 

  } else {
     return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still not working properly, but using that it'll actually run now, so thanks for getting me started here.

If I input AA I get 2731, BA gives me 3004, 0 gives me 1, 1 gives me 18, and so on in sort of a seemingly random order. But at least now I can compile it and see what's happening.

Comment: I'd guess you want pow(16, power-1) (the last digit is 10 * 16^0).  Edited the thing accordingly.

Comment: God damn, you're like some sort of wizard. It still doesn't work, but now some of the values are much closer. For example AA returns 171 when it should return 170. Some are only one off, while others are all over the place. For example, both -cf and -10 return -818. I'm getting closer though.

Comment: Hehe, 20+ years of programming (and taught C before). Unfortunately current can't compile here, so have to do it on the dry. See my edit on how to debug it, the printf() will lead the way, I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: I figured out why some were one off, it was because I was returning 1 instead of 0. Now the only things that aren't working are the negatives and that's easier. Again - thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome :-)  (checkmark for right answer would be appreciated)

Comment: Oh, and try to handle the '-' outside the recursion and just pass the hex digits to the function.  It will be a nightmare to handle that inside the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You're using post-increment here:

```
  return hexToDecimal(hex, offset--, power++)
```

Post-increment (and post-decrement) will increment/decrement the variable (i.e. it will actually *change* `offset` and `power`), but the inc/dec will happen *after* the variable is evaluated.

I.e.:

```
int i = 5;
std::cout << "i = " << i;     // prints 'i = 5'
std::cout << "\ni = " << i++; // still prints 'i = 5' and then changes i to be 6
std::cout << "\ni = " << i;   // prints 'i = 6'
```

You don't actually want to modify `offset` and `power` -- you want to pass a different value for these to the next `hexToDecimal` call.

You can catch these kind of mistakes if you make the method parameters `const`, i.e.:

```
int hexToDecimal(const char*hex, const int offset, const int power);
```

I recommend making parameters `const` when you have no intention to modify them.  That way the compiler can help you catch a lot of common mistakes.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. It makes sense why the other guy replaced them with 'offset - 1' and 'power + 1', I was a little lost why he was doing that.

Answer (score 1):

use predecrement in the the function argument . Use --offset in the argument.
if u use offset-- then intial value of offset is passed to function and then offset is decreased.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I wrote a LONG time ago...  It's probably not the best or fastest approach, and  could use some error checking, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader...

```
    long GetValue(const char *pszStrVal)
    {
      long Retval = 0;
      try {
        char *p = (char*)pszStrVal;
        if(p == NULL) return 0;

        if(strstr(p, "0x")) {
            p++;p++;
            long x = strlen(p);
            long pval = 1 << ((x-1)*4);

            for(int y = 0;y < x;y++,pval = (pval >> 4))
            {
                int digit = 0;
                switch(p[y])
                {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                    digit = 10;
                    break;
                case 'B':
                case 'b':
                    digit = 11;
                    break;
                case 'C':
                case 'c':
                    digit = 12;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'd':
                    digit = 13;
                    break;
                case 'E':
                case 'e':
                    digit = 14;
                    break;
                case 'F':
                case 'f':
                    digit = 15;
                    break;
                default:
                    digit = p[y] - 0x30;
                }

                Retval += (pval * digit);
            }
        } else {
            Retval = atoi(p);
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        Retval = 0;
    }
    return Retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that uses a second recursive function call. Hopefully it'll help you debug yours:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int h2d_rec(const char *hex, int d);

int h2d(const char *hex) {
    return h2d_rec(hex, 0);
}

int h2d_rec(const char *hex, int d) {
    char hexChar = *hex;
    if (0==hexChar) {
        return d;
    }
    int charNum;
    if (isalpha(hexChar)) {
        charNum = 10 + toupper(hexChar) - 'A';
    } else {
        charNum = hexChar - '0';
    }
    // Note d<<4 is the same as 16*d
    return h2d_rec(hex+1, (d<<4) + charNum);
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    const char *hex = "FF";

    if (1<argc) {
        hex = argv[1];
    }
    printf("%s in decimal is %d\n", hex, h2d(hex));
}
```

You might want to use `long` instead to handle bigger hex numbers.